# Historical detailed reporting for TestNG

Tags: testng, reporting

I need to create a report that displays test run result history - run stats (run #, passed, failed, skipped counts), failure details (failed test names, the exception message thrown), and some summarized reports (top 10 tests that failed the most, sorted descending, top 10 exceptions thrown, sorting descending).

I am currently getting date/passed/failed/skipped info from TestListenerAdapter's onFinish() method, and writing the results to a text file in JSON format:

`{date:%s,passed:%s,failed:%s,skipped:%s}`

which is being read from an HTML stacked bar graph.  I need to build upon this and collect the test details, i'm thinking like this:

`{date:%s,passed:%s,failed:%s,skipped:%s,details:{[failedTestName:%s,exceptionMsg:%s]}}`

My question is:

Am I heading down the right path for data collection and historical reporting? Is there something more out-of-the-box that i can use, or is customization the only way to go?  Typically i would collect and store results to a database, but that is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is working but TestListenerAdapter is usually used when you want real-time feedback.

Creating your own [reporter](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporters) seems to be a better approach because it will be only call once, at the end of the run.

Next, you can do what you want, even store the result in a database. 
But Jenkins with its TestNG plugin could be a good way to keep the history of runs.